# triggering a button on mainform without using main.Show(); from childform

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, parent-child

First of all, I am not experienced coder.

I have been coding a windows desktop application which uses a lot of forms. Main form has a panel that controls childforms and app makes calculations in thoose childforms than records results in ms-access database. I was wondering if I could reach button located in main form without usind Formmain main = new Formmain(); - main.Show();I would like to trigger that button on mainform automatically. I would love to know if that is possible.

Best regards.

Comment: You have a main form by itself. Why do you need to create a new main form to press the button? Auto trigger button - why not just write the method into load? I need more information on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I realised I didn't managed to explain my point specifically. Here is my problem step by step. Form main has a mainpanel that opens different childforms. Each childform has their own duties. In each childform,  program makes calculations and record results into a database. Once I open a new childform,  reaching Formmain (which is parent form) without using "Formmain main = new Formmain();" is my problem.  After all of that calculations, final result is being calculated again by a class and being stored in static double variable. I would love to write this final result into textbox on mainform.

Comment: Why does the main window disappear after your child window appears? Don't you understand how child windows return information to the main window? After using `ChildForm child=new ChildForm(); child.show();` in the main window. The main window will not disappear? I don't quite understand your logic. You can use delegated events \public properties\ or form result to interact with data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer again. My mainform never disapperas. here is code for each childform:
public Form activeForm = null;

private void Btn3_3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenChildForm(new Kat3_3());
        }

Comment: I will give you a demo. Please wait a few minutes.

Comment: For childform:
public Form activeForm = null;
        public void OpenChildForm(Form childForm)
        {
            if (activeForm != null)
                activeForm.Close();
            activeForm = childForm;
            childForm.TopLevel = false;
            childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            PanelMain.Controls.Add(childForm);
            PanelMain.Tag = childForm;
            childForm.BringToFront();
            childForm.Show();
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve something similar using the [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-7.0) control.

Because your data is in the database.

What you need is to add the judgment of the relevant data to the timer event and display the information on the textbox through your processing when the condition is passed.

Let me know if you have any questions, here is my demo:

These two buttons are demonstrations of the data operation results of the two subforms.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "I'm a ";
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Text = "test.";
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != "")
    {
        textBox3.Text = textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your patience and effort. I am going to try this. Since I am new to coding, first I neeed to udnerstnad where to implement this solution into my code. I will let you know the result.
Best regards.

Comment: You just need to drag the timer control into your main form and turn on the enabled property. Double-click the timer control and compile the timer_tick event. interval indicates how many milliseconds to run. You can change enabled to false when you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Allthough I wasn't able to explain my problem very well, I found a solution. Here is solution code for those who are suffering from same problem. Additionally thanks again @Jiale Xue for patience and effort.

Best regards.

```
FormKarbonMain karbonMain = (FormKarbonMain)Application.OpenForms["FormKarbonMain"];

karbonMain.txtAyakIzi.Text = toplamemisyon.ToString("N4");
```

Comment: I have already tried to mark your solution as "usefull" but since this is my first question in stackoverflow, system tells me that "I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote". 
Best regards.